# Shouldn't glClearColor() obey the drawing area set by glViewport()?

Tags: opengl

```
glViewport(x(), y(), width(), height());

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glClearColor(0, 0.3, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//... drawing commands
```

The drawing is correctly happening in a small area of the window, set by the `glViewport(x(), y(), width(), height())`

However, the background color set by glClearColor() is affecting the entire window, even though this is set after the call to glViewport(). Why?

Comment: I just wanted to make this note since I was having a problem where glClear was only clearing a portion of the screen when I had a texture bound to the FBO (some intermediate rendering step for a graph).

I understood glViewport to be set to the (lowerX, lowerY, width, height) where width and height are the resolution of the texture. 

What happened was I was not updating my depth buffer resolution to match , since I had the depth test disabled and thought it didn't matter. So the color attachment was not clearing completely. 

So maybe check your attachments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On [**`glClear`**](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml) side:

> The pixel ownership test, the scissor test, dithering, and the buffer writemasks affect the operation of `glClear`.

However, [**`glViewport`**](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) states that

> `glViewport` specifies the affine transformation of x and y from normalized device coordinates to window coordinates.

If I read the references correctly, this is by design; `glViewport` merely offsets the viewport, which affects the drawcalls which rasterize primitives, while `glClear` simply works on the whole framebuffer area.

The full spec (4.3) seems to agree with that:

> **§17.4.3** The GL provides a means for setting portions of every pixel in a particular buffer
>   to the same value.

Comment: It should be mentioned at least that `glScissor (...)` can be used to replicate the behavior the OP wants. Provided of course that `GL_SCISSOR_TEST` is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to clean up a small area, you need to enable GL_SCISSOR_TEST. Try the following code, hope this can help you.

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(100, 100, 100, 100);
glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```